# Will we hurt our body if we eat lunch/dinner after a workout?

Tags: exercise

Will we hurt our body if we eat lunch/dinner after a workout (3-5 minutes after a workout to be exact)?

If it will, how long must we wait before we can start having lunch/dinner after a workout?

Comment: Nah - What do you think our ancestors did after they finally caught that boar they were chasing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check out the last paragraph to my answer to [this](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/3274/should-i-eat-before-my-run/3328#3328) question.

> And I would absolutely recommend fueling with 20 minutes AFTER running. This is the time that your body will be best at absorbing fuel to help you recover and rebuild your glycogen stores. A recovery meal/shake/drink should be somewhere around 200-300 calories depending on body size and duration of exercise with about 20g of protein. The vendor's I mentioned above also have some quite good products for recovery.

You SHOULD be eating immediately after a workout.  The first 20 minutes after a work out are crucial in recovery.

Comment: could you simply add that paragraph to this answer as well? Saves a lot of people clicking through :)

Comment: like that?  good point.

Comment: I would add that it can be very helpful to combine the protein with something that will help carry it to the muscles faster, like sugar or another food with a high-glycemic index.

Comment: btw, how many minutes should we be waiting before we **drink**, or is it the same as **eating** (in that we can do that immediately after any workout)

Comment: I think drinking is fine, in fact you can drink (not too much of course) during your workout to prevent dehydration.

Comment: Yes, stay hydrated, for sure.  You should be consuming ~20-24 oz of liquid per hour.  For runs under an hour, you can safely not drink in most situations, but there is no harm in drinking.