# Do you have a post training window with regard to eating any foods?

Tags: nutrition

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it true that you can eat anything you want within 15 minutes of working out without putting on weight?](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/74/is-it-true-that-you-can-eat-anything-you-want-within-15-minutes-of-working-out-w)

My friend and I were having an argument where he was saying that you can pretty much eat any food after working out and even if its unhealthy, there is a window of time where your body is looking to replenish itself. [This article s](http://www.mensfitness.com/nutrition/what-to-eat/what-not-to-eat-after-a-workout)eems to agree with me but is there any truth to this comment?

Comment: I think this is a duplicate of the linked question, pretty much anything about diet timings is a myth.

Comment: @Informaficker I've experienced pretty clear post-workout differences in dairy and carb digestion, and read the science behind it. I'm also convinced by evidence for post-workout protein absorption being different. The "eat anything!" idea is hopelessly oversimplified, but let's not dismiss the whole thing as a myth.

Comment: @DaveLiepmann I might have been to radical, I wont rule out that the body behaves different directly after workout (or contrary while we sleep), but I don't think that the effect is as big as it is talked about sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say there is no truth to the statement that you can eat ANYTHING just because you just finished a workout. I mean no one is going to suggest that a tub of lard is ok as long as you worked out, right?

Now what your friend probably heard, and misinterpreted, is that after a hard workout where you have depleted your muscle's glycogen stores, they are best able to replenish them in the 30-60 minutes after.  Many endurance runners swear by a glass of chocolate milk at the end of a run, as the ratio of protein to carbs is just about optimal to replenish glycogen stores, possibly increasing the amount of glycogen stored, thereby increasing endurance in future workouts.